# How can I use Configuration in Net Core 6 worker app?

Tags: .net-core, configuration, worker

All information about using Configuation starts with creating builder and

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

subsequnetly using

```
builder.Configuration.
```

configuration ,but in Worker services WebApplication is not available.

How can i use Configuration in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker type of project?

Answer (score 14):

This might help https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/how-to-set-appsettings-or-config-in-a-net-worker-service-cc2d70ab4e0c

It is by accessing the HostBuilderContext

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
            services.Configure<RabbitMQConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(RabbitMQConfiguration)));
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you should add `ConfigureAppConfiguration` when `CreateHostBuilder`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configBuilder) =>
        {
            configBuilder
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
        });
```

Then, add configuration in appsettings.**YourEnv**.json

```
  "worker": {
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "SimpleWorker",
    "delay": 1000
  }
```

Add `IConfiguration` in `Worker` constructor and use it.

Full example of `Worker` class:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var workerConfig = _configuration.GetSection("worker").Get<SimpleWorkerConfig>();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker {id}:{name} running at: {time} with delay {delay}", 
                workerConfig.Id, workerConfig.Name, DateTimeOffset.Now, workerConfig.Delay);
            await Task.Delay(workerConfig.Delay, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleWorkerConfig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Delay { get; set; }
}
```

Result:
[image: Result]